# Multiple selector mass renaming plus number

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

Is it possible when you select bunch of lines with multiple selector to add class to each with some string or without regardless and add numbers starting from lets say number 1 on line one with increasing number on every next line. So you add to every line class + number+1.

For example:

```
class="name1"
class="name2"
class="name3"
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is built in command but you can achieve this with extension like [insert numbers extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Asuka.insertnumbers):
[image]

If you are generating markup, you can as well use Emmet [Item numbering](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#item-numbering):

[image]

Comment: This extension is exactly what I needed. Have complex SVG where I needed to inject a lot of IDs. Thanks man!